# How to launch charles proxy and auto save logs with certain configuration using java

Tags: java, charles-proxy

Is there any way to read charles proxy session programmatically using Java ? Basically I want to read specific logs from Charles proxy but my question is how can I start and save charles session so that I can read the data from the saved file using Java. Any help is highly apprecited. FYI, I have searched in this site but most of the questions were unanswered.

Comment: what is the reason of voting me down ?

Comment: seems to be a kind of weird thing to do... You should probably search for a better solution instead of launching CharlesProxy from your Java application.

Comment: Did my solution worked for you? if so, please mark it as valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your only option is to launch Charles as an external program from your java source code.
Take a look at how to do it [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html).